# dynamically combine bash functions into new shell file

Tags: bash, shell-script

Say I have a bunch of files:

```
a.sh
b.sh
c.sh
...
z.sh
```

and each of those files has a function in it like so:

```
   a(){
      echo "fooa" | bash
    }
```

now, **if** I could get all the functions in one file, they would look like:

```
   a(){
      echo "fooa" | bash
   }

   b(){
      echo "foob" | bash
   }

   c(){
      echo "fooc" | bash
   }
    ...
   z(){
      echo "fooz" | bash
   }
```

the problem is that they are in fact in separate files. What I am looking to do is dynamically write them to one file, so that one file can be sourced, instead of source 10 or 20 files.

What is the best way to do this?

One thing I could do is just loop through the files and append their contents to the 1 file that I want to source. Is there another way that might work?

Comment: `cat *.sh > all.sh`?

Comment: probably would work fine, any way to remove white space?

Comment: What's wrong with sourcing ? Or placing them in a folder and then sourcing everything in that folder ?

Comment: or creating another script that sources all of those files....

Comment: @AlexanderMills Removing whitespace would introduce syntax errors when the newlines are removed. Why are you piping to `bash`?

Comment: piping to bash just as an example, not really what I am doing

Comment: but yeah you're right removing whitespace is a bad idea

Answer (score 3):

`cat *.sh > all.sh` would concatenate all the files to one. That's a bit unclean, in that `*.sh` will also match `all.sh` if it already exists, but  the redirection will clear `all.sh` before `cat` runs here.

You could also just write one script to source all the others (call it `includeall.sh`):

```
for f in *.sh; do
    if [ "$f" != "includeall.sh" ]; then
        . "$f"
    fi
done
```

Then source that with `. includeall.sh`. The `if` is there to avoid re-including `includeall` itself. Though it might not be a bad idea to put the `a.sh`..`z.sh` scripts in a separate directory. That would make the directory structure cleaner, and make it harder to accidentally source any wrong scripts. `for f in dir/*.sh; do . "$f"; done` in that case.